# Execute a list of threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, list

I have a list of a object "Code":

```
List<Code> listCodes = new List<Code>();
```

I need to execute each code inside the list in a Thread, but I have not idea how to do that, because I tried to do something like:

```
foreach(Code c in listCodes)
{
   Thread tr = new Thread(delegate() {
      Execute(c.CodeLine);
   });
}
```

This foreach is in a timer, because those Codes will be executed all the time, but when I do that the same code is executed a lot of times even if the first execution wasn't finished, if the code takes like 5 seconds to be executed and finished and the timer is 500ms it will be executed 10 times if I disable the timer after 5 seconds for exemple.

I couldn't think anything to execute the codes in the list, each one in their thread, but I want to execute the thread of the code 0(for exemple) only if it was finished after the execution.

Thank you.

Comment: That timer is pretty ugly.  As presented there's no reason for it, you might as well loop inside the thread and use a ManualResetEvent to stop the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`System.Threading.Monitor.TryEnter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4tssbxcw.aspx) is perfect for the job:

```
foreach(Code c in listCodes) {
   Code a = c;

   new Thread(delegate() {
       if(Monitor.TryEnter(a)) {
           Execute(a.CodeLine);
           Monitor.Exit(a);
       }
   }) { IsBackground = true }.Start();
}
```

What it does is try to acquire an exclusive lock on the `Code` object. If it can't (i.e. the `Code` is already executing) then nothing will happen; otherwise, the lock is acquired, and released when execution is complete.

Comment: Won't you release the exclusive lock the moment the thread starts executing?  Control is returned to the caller immediately after Execute().

Comment: @EricJ.: No, the locking code is inside the thread, not the loop.

Comment: LOL missed that.  So used to TPL now that I read past the explicit thread creation.

Comment: Why are you releasing the lock even if you didn't take it? That doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: You didn't fix it.  Locking public objects is quite questionable as well.

Comment: Why not just use `lock` - which is kind of shorthand for Monitor Enter and Exit? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf5de04k.aspx

Comment: @Nayan: Because it's shorthand for *Enter*, not *TryEnter*?

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks, it's really fixed this time. And I think the object is the best choice for locking; if it causes issues somewhere else, it's obvious and not difficult to change.

Comment: Also, this code won't do anything, because you don't actually `Start()` the threads. And since you access the loop variable in an anonymous function, you will most likely only execute the last `Code` several times (unless you're using C# 5).

Comment: @svick: Thank you. I must have been very tired yesterday. Is there anything else? I think I got them all...

Answer (score 1):

I think using `Thread`s like this is inefficient, you should use `Task`s instead.

In C# 5, I would do it like this:

```
private static async Task RunCode(Code code, TimeSpan delay)
{
    while (!Stopped)
    {
        var delayTask = Task.Delay(delay);

        Execute(code.CodeLine);

        await delayTask;
    }
}
```

And then start it once (i.e. not in a timer):

```
foreach (Code c in listCodes)
{
    Task.Run(() => RunCode(c, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually wait for the `Thread`s to finish. You do this by calling `Join`:

```
List<Thread> threads = new List<Threads>();

foreach(Code c in listCodes)
{
   Thread tr = new Thread(delegate() {
      Execute(c.CodeLine);
   });
   threads.Add(tr);
}

foreach(Thread tr in threads)
{
   tr.Join();
}
```

This is all inside your outer timer.

Comment: That will block the main thread until all other threads complete, which would require the Code threads to be Execute'd on a thread that can block.